# Find the result of a weird looking sum

Tags: summation, contest-math

How do I find the value of such ridiculous-looking sum?

$$\sum^{100}_{i=1}\lfloor \sqrt{i}\rfloor$$

Comment: For a given $x$, how many $i \in \mathbb N$ are there such that $\lfloor\sqrt i\rfloor = x$?

Comment: Start calculating. There is a nice pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  Think about how many values $i$ starting from $1$ such that $1\leq\sqrt{i}<2$, then $2\leq\sqrt{i}<3$, so on until $9\leq\sqrt{i}<10$.  This should help you get started.